# where is Application.ExternalCall("console.log", msg) output?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I used console.log in my code, but when I run this, I don't know how to find the output log.

I tried to open "View -> developer -> JavaScript Console", but can't see the debug log. So where is the log?

```
        if (Application.isWebPlayer)
            Application.ExternalCall("console.log", msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the right console.

You could try making an `ExternalCall` to `alert` instead of `console.log` maybe the dot notation is not supported. If that is the case then try logging through custom function. Put this in your HTML:

```
<script>
function my_console_log(msg_from_unity) {
      console.log(msg_from_unity);
}
</script>
```